# Membresia no me aparece (Nuevo miembro)

Tags: civimember

En el desplegable de Membresia no me aparece la opcion de nuevo miembro. Lo tengo instalado sobre wordpress.

gracias por la ayuda.

=== From Google Translate:

Membership does not appear (New member)

In the Membership dropdown, the new member option does not appear. I have it installed on wordpress.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

ya he encontrado la solucion:

Administrar-Pantallas y Datos Personalizados-Menu Navegacion
En el listado pulsar en
Membership-New Membership editar y habilitar

Saludos.

=== Google Translate:

I have already found the solution:

Manage-Custom Screens and Data-Navigation Menu In the list click on Membership-New Membership edit and enable

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

Have you enabled the Membership component?

Have you defined Membership Types?

Comment: gracias por la bienvenida y la rapida contestacion.
el tipo de membresia si he creado uno pero la permanencia no veo donde es. gracias de nuevo

Comment: Google Translate: Thanks for the welcome and the quick reply. The type of membership if I have created one but I don't see where the permanence is.

Thanks again